# Why does one make TTT Plot instead of Empirical Hazard Rate Plot?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, survival, data-visualization, hazard

The total time on test (TTT) transform procedure is used as a tool to identify the hazard behavior of the data distribution. There is a correspondence of the TTT plot and the shape of the empirical hazard rate.

My question is: If one wants to know the empirical hazard rate shape from a data, why does one *usually (on my observation)* make TTT plot instead of making an empirical hazard rate plot of the data directly *(just like one make an empirical cdf directly from data)*?

Is it hard to make an empirical hazard rate plot of the data directly? Or is there any other reason(s)?